# adding a textView underneath another textView

Tags: android, view, textview, android-linearlayout

Currently I want to make a custom UI in java code and not worry about xml files. I'm at the point where I want to add a textView underneath an already existing textView in my linearLayout. Here's what I have so far.

```
View linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.rockLayout);
        ImageView mineralPicture = new ImageView(this);
        TextView mineralName = new TextView(this);
        TextView mineralProperties = new TextView(this);
        mineralProperties.setText("The properties are: " + Statics.rockTable.get(rockName).getDistinctProp());
        mineralProperties.setId(2);
        mineralName.setText("This mineral is: " + rockName);
        mineralName.setId(1);
        mineralName.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        mineralProperties.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        /** Need to figure out the picture....
         * mineralPicture.setId(2);
         * mineralPicture.setImageResource(R.drawable.rocks);
         * mineralPicture.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
         */

            ((LinearLayout)linearLayout).addView(mineralName);
        ((LinearLayout)linearLayout).addView(mineralProperties);
```

The problem is that it only adds the mineralName textView and not the mineralProperties textView. I would like for it be the mineralName textView on the very top, then the mineralProperties textView right underneath it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Child views in a LinearLayout will be stacked horizontally by default. Try changing that with `linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL)`.

Also you should change your text view layout params to:

```
mineralName.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

mineralProperties.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Otherwise one of the views might cover the other.

Answer (score 1):

your code is working with small changes, hope it can help you.

```
View linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.rockLayout);
       ImageView mineralPicture = new ImageView(this);
        TextView mineralName = new TextView(this);
        TextView mineralProperties = new TextView(this);
        mineralProperties.setText("The properties are: " + Statics.rockTable.get(rockName).getDistinctProp());

        mineralProperties.setId(2);
        mineralName.setText("This mineral is: " + rockName);
        mineralName.setId(1);
```

**Change MATCH_PARENT with WRAP_CONTENT**

```
        mineralName.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        mineralProperties.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        /** Need to figure out the picture....
         * mineralPicture.setId(2);
         * mineralPicture.setImageResource(R.drawable.rocks);
         * mineralPicture.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
         */

        ((LinearLayout)linearLayout).addView(mineralName);
        ((LinearLayout)linearLayout).addView(mineralProperties);
```